# SQLite Syntax error

Tags: sql, sqlite

Hi I'm having a problem with one of the tables in my database. I'm loading the tables from a .txt file, when I load the database i get

```
ERROR NEAR line 49: near "(": syntax error
```

the table below starts from line 49

```
create table LEASE(
P_ID integer,
I_ID varchar2,
C_ID integer,
DATE date,
TRENT decimal(6,2),
RENTPM decimal(4,2),
RENTUTD varchar2 constraint rentutd_value (RENTUTD in ('Y','N')),
LENGTH varchar2(15),
SDATE date,
EDATE date,
NOTE varchar2(150),
G_ID integer,
A_ID integer,
constraint fkey_lea1 foreign key (P_ID) references PROPERTY(P_ID),
constraint fkey_lea2 foreign key (I_ID) references INSTITUTION(I_ID),
constraint fkey_lea3 foreign key (C_ID) references CLIENT(C_ID),
constraint fkey_lea4 foreign key (G_ID) references GUARANTOR(G_ID),
constraint fkey_lea5 foreign key (A_ID) references AGENT(A_ID),
constraint pkey_lea primary key (P_ID,I_ID,C_ID,DATE)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the syntax on your `rentutd`  column needs to be a little different:

```
RENTUTD varchar2 constraint rentutd_value CHECK ( RENTUTD in ('Y','N'))
```

See this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/f516b).

The [SQLite syntax diagrams](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#column-constraint) are great to figure this stuff out.

Comment: Thanks, I spent so long looking at the foreign key and primary key syntax I only glanced at the rest of the table.